# In Web API 2, how can I determine which action will be invoked in Application_PostResolveRequestCache?

Tags: asp.net-web-api2

I'm trying to figure out what data I need to provide `ApiControllerActionSelector.SelectAction(controllerContext)` with in order to accurately determine the action that will be invoked.

I need to do this in `Application_PostResolveRequestCache` because I have to use the result of the determination to decide which one of several different dependencies will be injected for a given interface.

To create the `HttpControllerContext` I'm passing in, I've been using this method (copied almost verbatim from `HttpControllerDispatcher`):

```cs
private static HttpControllerContext CreateControllerContext(
    HttpRequestMessage request,
    HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor
)
{
    HttpConfiguration configuration1 = controllerDescriptor.Configuration;
    HttpConfiguration configuration2 = request.GetConfiguration();
    if (configuration2 == null)
    {
        request.SetConfiguration(configuration1);
    }
    else if (configuration2 != configuration1)
    {
        request.SetConfiguration(configuration1);
    }

    HttpRequestContext httpRequestContext1 = request.GetRequestContext();
    var controller = (IHttpController) FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(controllerDescriptor.ControllerType);
    return new HttpControllerContext(httpRequestContext1, request, controllerDescriptor, controller);
}
```

When I call this method, the `RouteData` property of the returned `HttpControllerContext` is always `null`. I haven't been able to figure out where to get the "correct" one, and I *think* that's the only piece I'm missing here.

The main question still remains in the title: how can I determine which action will be invoked before the controller which will handle the current request has been created?

Answer (score 0):

Turns out I was, in fact, simply missing the correct instance of `IHttpRouteData` - the `HttpRouteData` instances that come from `HttpContext.Current.Request.RequestContext.RouteData.Values["MS_SubRoutes"]` don't contain enough information to determine the route unambiguously. For that, you need a `HostedHttpRouteData` instance.

For whatever reason, the developers didn't see fit to expose the `HostedHttpRouteData` class (it's `internal`), so you can't instantiate one directly. I worked around that by stealing one from an `HttpControllerHandler`. Here's the method I ended up with:

```cs
private (HttpActionDescriptor actionDescriptor, HttpControllerDescriptor controllerDescriptor) FindMatchingAction(
    IHttpHandler routeHandler,
    HttpRequestMessage requestMessage,
    IEnumerable<HttpControllerDescriptor> controllerDescriptors
)
{
    var actionSelector = new SnakeCaseActionSelector();
    var requestContext = requestMessage.GetRequestContext();
    var routeData = (IHttpRouteData) typeof(HttpControllerHandler)
        .GetField("_routeData", BindingFlags.Instance | BindingFlags.NonPublic)
        ?.GetValue(routeHandler);

    foreach (var controllerDescriptor in controllerDescriptors)
    {
        var controller = FormatterServices.GetUninitializedObject(controllerDescriptor.ControllerType) as IHttpController;
        if (requestMessage.GetConfiguration() == null || requestMessage.GetConfiguration() != controllerDescriptor.Configuration)
        {
            requestMessage.SetConfiguration(controllerDescriptor.Configuration);
        }

        var controllerContext = new HttpControllerContext(requestContext, requestMessage, controllerDescriptor, controller)
        {
            RouteData = routeData
        };
        try
        {
            return (actionSelector.SelectAction(controllerContext), controllerDescriptor);
        }
        catch (HttpResponseException)
        {
            ; // Too bad!! No matching actions found on this controller...try again maybe?
        }
    }

    // Badder still!! No matching actions found at all!
    throw new HttpResponseException(
        requestMessage.CreateErrorResponse(
            HttpStatusCode.NotFound,
            $"No route found matching {HttpContext.Current.Request.Url.AbsolutePath}"
        )
    );
}
```